# Using ES6 Set as a dependency to useEffect(). Effect not called on changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, set, react-hooks

I want to use the ES6 `Set` in my React component, with `useState()` and `useEffect()`. It works great with `useState()`, but the `useEffect()` is not triggered when the `Set` dependency is changed.

Here's the relevant code. `onChange()` is memoized.

```
const Filter = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Set())

  console.log("Selected Set", selected)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect")
    onChange(Array.from(selected))
  }, [selected, onChange])

  const handleClick = (topic) => {
    selected.add(topic)
  }

  return (
    <div className="filter">

    </div>
  )
}
```

I know I can do this with an `Array`, but it would be nice to be able to take advantage of the helpful properties of `Set` without creating helper functions every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is coming from that you are trying to modify directly the state `selected`. Even if you are using `Set` you still need to use the setter `setSelected` to trigger the change with is affecting `useEffect` once you have `selected` in the dependency list.

I would try somehow the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('effect');

  // your actions ...
}, [selected]);

const handleClick = (topic) => {
  const newSelected = new Set(selected);
  newSelected.add(topic);
  setSelected(newSelected);
}
```

By using `new Set(selected)` you are making a shallow copy of `Set` from `selected` using the constructor. Then you can add new items to the newly created `Set`. Lastly you need to use `setSelected` to update `selected` value which will trigger the `useEffect` as you expected earlier.

I hope that helps!

Comment: @eivindml That happens, happy to solved your issue.

Comment: Using set ended up more verbose that just using array, even though Set has that "insert only unique" property I was after. Because with Set I had to 1. create copy of set before `add()`, 2. compare new and old set so that we don't update state when they still are the same, 3. convert set to array in the effect. With array I only had to do 2. :P

Comment: @eivindml I think this was still a good question, even though it seems more work than using an array as you mentioned.